# perl subroutine from reading STDIN ("Press enter to reset") only works the first time

Tags: perl, stdin, subroutine

I have made a little perl program for a kids demonstration and I'm trying to keep the screen clean and simple with a `clear` subroutine, but it's only working the first time, and then will not respond to input, only clearing the screen, and I can't work out why. I'm also sure that there's a simpler way to do this in general, so maybe the whole thing should be scrapped.

There is a prompt for a query from STDIN, then once it's checked the database it calls the `restart` sub.

What I have:

```
while (my $seq = <STDIN>){
  chomp($seq);
  if (exists $references{$seq}){
    ... blah blah blah
    sleep(2);
    &restart;
  }else{
    print "\nOops! This  doesn't exist!\n";
    sleep(2);
    &restart;
  }
}
sub restart {
  print "\nPress Enter to restart\n";
  while (my $in = <STDIN>){
   if($in eq "\n"){
     system("clear");
     print $prompt;
   }
  }
}
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Does it fail to clear the screen but otherwise continue executing? Does it hang? Does it do something else?

Comment: Sorry, yeah it wasn't clear. I added more detail above, but Politank-Z below has pointed out the problem so it's solved now.

Comment: Unrelated: `&restart` should be `restart()`

Comment: Why is this? I see people say to avoid the &, but my Learning Perl Schwartz book says that's the way to do it. Obviously it's a bit old now but why did it change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `sub restart` you are looping on `<STDIN>` again. This will continue to loop, without returning to the main loop, until STDIN receives an EOF. You could put a `return` after `print $prompt;` to return to the main loop.

Comment: Perfect thanks! It seems so obvious when someone explains it to you!